# Uploaded .txt file through POSTMAN gets corrupted (appended with Content-Disposition, Content-type) JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, jax-rs, postman

Greetings to the community! I am currently developing a `RESTful web service` in `Java` using the `JAX-rs` library. What I would like to do is make clients able to upload a file via the service. I successfully managed to achieve this using the following piece of code

```
@Consumes({"application/json"})
@Produces({"application/json"})
@Path("uploadfileservice")
public interface UploadFileService {

   @Path("/fileupload")
   @POST
   @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
   Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream)
}
```

**Implementation class**

```
@Service
public class UploadFileServiceImpl implements UploadFileService {

@Override
public Response uploadFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream){
String fileToWrite = "//path/file.txt" //assuming a upload a txt file
writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, fileToWrite); //write the file
}

private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    String uploadedFileLocation) {

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
}
```

I am using `POSTMAN` as a client to test my web service and I am facing the following problem: **When I upload a .txt file, that files gets appended with some other details of the file**

Example:

File sent

[image: file sent]

Postman Request

[image: postman request]

File stored on my filesystem

[image: file stored]

Any idea why this happens? Maybe I am missing something in the `Headers` section of my request? Or maybe any issue is caused because of the `MediaType` I am consuming in my web service endpoint?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

**PS**

If I upload a .pdf file it is not leaded to corruption and the .pdf file is stored normally on my filesystem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a workaround for my problem using the `Attachment` class of `org.apache.cxf`:

```
@Consumes({"application/json"})
@Produces({"application/json"})
@Path("uploadfileservice")
public interface UploadFileService {

@Path("/fileupload")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
Response uploadFile(@Multipart("file") Attachment attr)
}



@Service
public class UploadFileServiceImpl implements UploadFileService {

@Override
public Response uploadFile(Attachment attr){
String pathToUpload= "//path//.txt"
try{
  attr.transferTo(new File(pathToUpload)); //will copy the uploaded file in 
  //this destination
}
catch(Exception e){

}

}
```

Comment: It's not a workaround. If you are using CXF, `@FormDataParam` will not work, as that's for Jersey. The `@Multipart` you are using is for CXF. These are different implementations, and the multipart support for each implementation is different and not compatible.

Comment: But I do not use FormDataParam anymore as you can see, I changed it to org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Multipart

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature should be

```
Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") FormDataBodyPart uploadedFile)
```

and you can get content of the file as

```
InputStream uploadedInputStream = uploadedFile.getValueAs(InputStream.class)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, should I include any special headers in my POSTMAN request? Because I added Content-Type = multipart/form-data and no Headers at all and received a 415 Unsupported Media Type exception

Comment: In POSTMAN, you don't have to set **Content-Type** header if you are using **multipart/form-data**. For details refer https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/191